# How to find a complex root of $x^{2021}=x^{2020}+1$ while this complex root also satisfies a quadratic equation with integer coefficients?

Tags: contest-math

How to find a complex root of $x^{2021}=x^{2020}+1$ while this complex root also satisfies a quadratic equation with integer coefficients? I have no previous experience in solving complex equations so just have no clue on this kind of question... Is there any useful pattern on this?

Comment: Obviously, the first thing to do is to look at what happens to $x^{N+1}-x^N-1$ when $N=2020$ is replaced by smaller, more manageable values. Give it a try.

Comment: __Hint:__ $x^5 - x^4 - 1 = (x^2 - x + 1) ( x^3 - x - 1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^5 - x^4 - 1 = (x^2 - x + 1) ( x^3 - x - 1)$.

$ $

> **Hint:** $x^3 +1 = (x^2 - x + 1 ) ( x + 1)$.

$ $

> Hence, $ x^{6n+k} \equiv x^{k} \pmod{x^2-x+1}$

$ $

> Hence $ x^{2021} - x^{2020} - 1 \equiv x^5 - x^4 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2-x+1}$.